# Spring can't autowire class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

I have the following Spring @Configuration:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("mongo")
public MongoFacade mongo(Environment env){
    final String host = env.getProperty("database.host");
    final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(host);
    return new MongoFacade(mongoClient, "test-db");
}

@Bean
public MessageStore<Event> eventStore(@Qualifier("mongo") MongoFacade mongo, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new MongoMessageStore<>(mongo, mapper);
}
```

When I launch my application an exception is thrown and the cause is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventStore' defined in it.m.MyConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [base.backend.persistence.impl.mongo.MongoFacade]: : No qualifying bean of type [base.backend.persistence.impl.mongo.MongoFacade] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=mongo)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [base.backend.persistence.impl.mongo.MongoFacade] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=mongo)}
```

`MongoFacade` class is a real class, and don't implements interfaces, I've also tried to remove the `Environment` dependency from the method, but still doesn't work.

Removing the `@Qualifier` annotation the error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [base.backend.persistence.impl.mongo.MongoFacade] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

MongoFacade is a simple facade for MongoClient class that works with my PersistenceId class:

```
public class MongoFacade {

public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "default";

private final MongoClient mongo;
private final String defaultName;

public MongoFacade(MongoClient mongoClient) {
    this(mongoClient, DEFAULT_NAME);
}
public MongoFacade(MongoClient mongoClient, String defaultName) {
    this.mongo = mongoClient;
    this.defaultName = defaultName;
}

public Document findOne(PersistenceId id){
    final MongoCollection<Document> collection = collection(id);
    final String documentId = documentId(id);

    return collection.find(eq("_id", documentId)).first();
}

public UpdateResult updateOne(PersistenceId id, Document update) {
    final MongoCollection<Document> collection = collection(id);
    final String documentId = documentId(id);

    return collection.updateOne(eq("_id", documentId), update);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste what MongoFacade looks like?

Comment: ok added the class to the question

Comment: Aren't you missing @Autowired here ?@Bean
public MessageStore<Event> eventStore( HERE@Autowired @Qualifier("mongo") MongoFacade mongo, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new MongoMessageStore<>(mongo, mapper);
}

Comment: no it is not needed, the problem was the method name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment can be injected as a field instead of the constructor also I would suggest using method calls instead of auto wiring for the dependencies.

Something like the following

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public MongoFacade mongoFacade(){
    final String host = env.getProperty("database.host");
    final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(host);
    return new MongoFacade(mongoClient, "test-db");
}

@Bean
public MessageStore<Event> eventStore(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new MongoMessageStore<>(mongoFacade(), mapper);
}
```

**Edit:** Added Spring Boot MongoDB config

From the comments it is clear you are using Spring Boot, this already [auto configures](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb) a `MongoClient` for you. Instead of doing it yourself you can reduce your configuration a little further. (Se also [`MongoAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.java)).

In your `application.properties` add

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=<value of current database.host>
```

or if it is a full URI

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=<value of current database.host>
```

Then change your configuration class.

```
@Bean
public MongoFacade mongoFacade(MongoClient mongoClient){
    return new MongoFacade(mongoClient, "test-db");
}

@Bean
public MessageStore<Event> eventStore(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new MongoMessageStore<>(mongoFacade(null), mapper);
}
```

Spring Boot will now construct a `MongoClient`.

Comment: With the method call isn't the object created two times?

Comment: No. The class is processed in a special way and a proxy is created which intercepts the method calls.

Comment: arg...spring has too much magic in it...I've changed my code and now I have this exception: 
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [base.backend.persistence.contract.MessageStore]: Factory method 'eventStore' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.MongoClient cannot be cast to base.backend.persistence.impl.mongo.MongoFacade` this ClassCastException upset me...

Comment: Ehrm I can hardly believe that that makes it work, change the name of the method from `mongo` to `mongoFacade` and please re-add the `@Bean` method else it will not be a spring managed bean (which can be needed if it contains callbacks for instance).

Comment: Let me guess `MessageStore` has a `MongoClient` field named `mongo`?

Comment: no, `MessageStore` has a `private MongoFacade mongo`, but `MongoFacade` has `private MongoClient mongo` field (without `setMongo` method). So, do you think that Spring tries to inject that field?

Comment: Not if there isn't an `@Autowired` on that. I also don't see why the `MongoClient` is all of a sudden a bean. Are you using Spring Boot or something?

Comment: I don't have any `@Autowired` annotation on my classes, but I use SpringBoot, does it do something automagically?

Comment: That already exposes a `MongoClient` with the name `mongo`. If yu are using Spring Boot then simply let that configure MongoDB for you (and instead of your facade you might want to use the `MongoTemplate` instead.

Comment: mmm no I need my MongoFacade, but this for me is one reason more to remove spring from the project :)

Comment: You don't need to remove Spring, the fact that you don't understand it fully yet shouldn't be a reason to remove it. You can make your code easier as you don't need to construct the `MongoClient` as that is already done for you. You only need to specify `spring.mongodb.host={value of database.host}` and have the `MongoClient` passed into the method. See [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.java) for what is configured for you.

Comment: No I don't like hidden features, and stuff like that, I don't like proxies class and this magic that happens suddenly also to do a simple stuff like create an object (before I used to create that object with a new and it works easily), the only reason I am using spring is for the MVC Controller, this is why I want to remove it and choose something more lightweight and less magic :) I don't want do lose 2 hours to have an instance of `MongoClient` because I didn't read the source code of SpringBoot

Comment: You don't have to read the source code of Spring Boot, [the MongoDB chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb) of the reference guide would have been enough (which shouldn't have taken more then 5 minutes). Those "magic features" make so that you can focus on what you need to do write business logic instead of infrastructure, error handling, transaction code, the same reason you are using Spring MVC (you don't want to write a plain servlet and do conversion etc. yourself generally speaking).

Comment: If you don't know how to solve that kind of problem yes Spring is a good framework, but for me that I don't want Spring manage the mongodb stuff why it create a bean automagically without that I configured nothing? How many other stuff spring does without that I know it? This is what I don't want, I want to have control over my software....Then spring help with a lot of stuff with a lot of magic.

Comment: I like Spring, but right now it does too much stuff automatically, this is way I'm thinking to move to Guice and Jersey (or directly Jetty), but I'm talking for my case, for others it can be very comfortable have it manage everything

Comment: Guice is also for auto wiring. Please don't confuse Spring Boot with auto configuration with Spring... You are mixing a lot of things here.

Comment: If you don't want the whole auto configuration stuff, just remove Spring Boot and configure the beans you need.

Comment: I don't know how to start SpringMVC inside Jetty, do you know some guide/tutorial/manual?

Answer (score 0):

can you please use @Service instead of @qualifier while declaring bean definition

```
@Service("mongo")
public MongoFacade mongoFacade()
```

let me know if it worked for you or not .